# How to pass vertex attribute name to a function in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I´m trying to write a custom function that evaluates how many triangles in a network are balanced with respect to a specific vertex attribute. Importantly, the name of the attribute should be customizable in the function call.

Example:

```
# Creating graph
A <- graph(c("a","b",
             "a","c",
             "c","b",
             "d","e",
             "e","a",
             "d","f",
             "f","e",
             "g","a",
             "g","e"),
           directed = FALSE)

V(A)$color <- c("lightblue",
                "lightcoral",
                "lightcoral",
                "lightblue",
                "lightblue",
                "lightblue",
                "lightcoral")

V(A)$shape <- c("circle",
                "circle",
                "circle",
                "square",
                "square",
                "square",
                "square")
```

I want a function that lets me check how many of the triangles in `A` are balanced with respect to `color`, `shape`, or any other attribute that ther vertices might have.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
TriadBalance  <- function(network,attribute){

        # Getting a List of all closed triangles in the network
        TriMat <- matrix(triangles(network), nrow=3)
        TriList <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(TriMat)), function(i) TriMat[,i])

        # Getting their attribute
        AttributeList <- lapply(TriList,function(x){return(V(network)[unlist(x)]$attribute)})

        # Checking if the attribute is the same in all triads
        Balance <- lapply(AttributeList, function(x){length(unique(unlist(x))) == 1})

        # counting the number of balanced triads
        NoBalance <- sum(unlist(Balance))

        return(NoBalance)

}
```

The error in this approach occurs in this line: `AttributeList <- lapply(TriList,function(x){return(V(network)[unlist(x)]$attribute)})` because the `$attribute` part does not evaluate to the corresponding input in the function call.

Core of the Problem:

```
attribute = "color"
V(A)[c(1,2,3)]$attribute

V(A)[c(1,2,3)]$color
```

The first two arugments returns NULL, the second one correctly outputs the vertex attribute for the first three nodes.

Is there a different way to pass a vertex attribute name from a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show how to get the attribute values as a small function,  but you could probably just put the code inline in your function. To get the attribute by its name, just `grep` the attribute names to figure out the index of the attribute, then access the attribute by its index number.

```
library(igraph)

SelectVAttr = function(graph, aName) {
    NamePattern = paste0("^", aName, "$")
    Index = grep(NamePattern, names(vertex_attr(graph)))
    vertex_attr(graph)[[Index]]
}

## Using the example that you provided
SelectVAttr(A, "color")
[1] "lightblue"  "lightcoral" "lightcoral" "lightblue"  "lightblue" 
[6] "lightblue"  "lightcoral"
SelectVAttr(A, "shape")
[1] "circle" "circle" "circle" "square" "square" "square" "square"
```

The NamePattern is to insure that you only get exact matches - not just partial matches.

Comment: `graph` is the formal parameter in my function. However, the name of the actual graph in the OP's example was `A`